# How to remove jquery mobile button color or override button css?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile in my sample project. I have three buttons. I am changing the style of the buttons (adding my own CSS) so that it overrides jQuery button CSS. But while adding it still shows some small white background. I inspect the page and find it is jQuery mobile button. I am not able to override that background. Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/5DDBD/

```
.ui-grid-c .ui-btn-inner {
    background: #2b6dbc; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    border-radius: 3px; 
    width: 100px; 
    text-shadow: none; 
    margin-left: 4px; 
}
```

Using the DOM inspector, when I removed this `background: 2b6dbc` it will show jQuery mobile button.

How can I remove that?

After adding this, it changing the color  on focus and unfocus.

```
.ui-btn-up-c{background:#2b6dbc; color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:3px; width:100px; text-shadow:none; margin-left:4px;}
```

Comment: Looks like your `.ui-btn-inner`'s width is wider than the `.ui-btn`...

Comment: how to change that..?

Comment: I added a response below. You are changing the with of the inner, but you forgot to change the width of the button itself.

Comment: this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5DDBD/6/

Comment: yes omar got it nice answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the `ui-btn` directly: http://jsfiddle.net/5DDBD/5/

```css
.ui-btn {
    background: #2B6DBC;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.ui-btn-inner {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: note that will change all elements with `ui-btn` and `ui-btn-inner`. Its advisable to identify them by a custom class i.e. `.ui-custom .ui-btn`

Answer (score 0):

The CSS are inheriting from  ".ui-btn-up-c" class. It is defined in your "c" theme (data-theme = c).

So the best way to define your own "c" theme in Theme Roller jquery Mobile. http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Or you can change the background from ".ui-btn-up-c".

Comment: can you do some change on my fiddle for better understand

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom css to .ui-btn instead of .ui-btn-inner

```
.ui-grid-c .ui-btn
{
background:#2b6dbc; 
color:#FFFFFF; 
border:1px solid #000; 
border-radius:3px; 
width:100px; 
text-shadow:none;
margin-left:4px; 
}
```

See here.. http://jsfiddle.net/5DDBD/2/

Comment: but previous button is not looking good..!! if the width of all buttons same it look good..?

Answer (score 0):

"`.ui-grid-c > :nth-child(n)`" on jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css, you can fixed it:

```
.ui-grid-c > :nth-child(n){
/* width: 25% */
margin-right:5px;
border:none;
}
```

and "`.ui-grid-c .ui-btn-inner`" remove `margin-left:4px` property.

Comment: can you change on my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the width and margin-left properties from .ui-grid-c .ui-btn-inner.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you just wanted to remove the white space around the button. I can see you already found the answer so no need to modify mine.